# Android Parse Query include specific column from Pointer

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have 2-classes `PendingFriends` & User. The `PendingFriends` class has a column with a User pointer in it.

But I do not require the entire `User` pointer data. I just want 1-field ,ie, `userStatus` (which is a string value). Is it possible?

Current code returns the entire user-pointer:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PendingFriends");
    query.whereEqualTo(KEY_BOTH, currentUser);
    query.include( "user2" );
    query.whereNotEqualTo("isDeleted", true);
    query.whereNotEqualTo("isUnfriend", true);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
    {...
```

**Edit:**

I try to do this but I get the following error:

> field userStatus cannot be included because it is not a pointer to
>   another object

```
query.include( "user2.userStatus" );
```

Comment: Hi there, did you find a good solution